# android fragment in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a listView that has a custom layout that contains a fragment.  The problem I am having is when I add the fragment to the listView row I get a never ending loop that keeps going through the getView code.

I have only been doing Android coding for a couple months so any help would be great.  Please let me know if there is any more of my code I need to post

This is my adapter code:

```
class AdapterReply(
    private val context: Context,
    private val ph: Phan,
    private val replies: ArrayList<Reply> ) : BaseAdapter() {

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return replies.size
}
override fun getItem(position: Int): Reply {
    return replies[position]
}
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View? {
    val rowMain: View?
    val rowHolder: ListRowHolder
    val contacts = ph.contacts
    val reply = replies[position]
    Log.d("AdapterReply", "Binding reply: Position $position ${reply.id} Detail: ${reply.detail}")
    if (convertView == null) {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup!!.context)
        rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reply_item_row, viewGroup, false)
        rowHolder = ListRowHolder(rowMain)
        rowMain.tag = rowHolder
        Log.d("AdapterReply", "New Item")
    } else {
        rowMain = convertView
        rowHolder = rowMain.tag as ListRowHolder
        Log.d("AdapterReply", "Old item from memory")
    }
    rowHolder.itemDetail.text = Helpers.anonymizeContent(reply.detail, ph.anonymousMetadata, ph.isViewerMember())
    rowHolder.itemLastActive.text = Helpers.getFormattedDate(reply.lastActive())


    if(reply.attachments.size > 0){
        val imageAttachment = reply.attachments.filter { attachment: Attachment -> attachment.type == 0 }[0]
        var imageUrl = Constants.BASE_URL + imageAttachment.url
        if(imageAttachment.anonymous()){
            imageUrl = Constants.BASE_URL + imageAttachment.anonUrl
        }
        Picasso.with(rowMain!!.context).load(imageUrl).into(rowHolder.itemImage)
    }
    var poster: Contact? = reply.contact
    if(contacts.size > 0) {
        val posterList = contacts.filter { contact: Contact -> contact.id == reply.rlContactID }
        if (posterList.isNotEmpty()) {
            poster = posterList[0]
        }
    }
    if(poster != null) {
        if(poster.anonymizedName.isNotEmpty()) {
            rowHolder.itemPoster.text = poster.anonymizedName
        } else {
            val posterName = "${poster.firstName} ${poster.lastName}"
            rowHolder.itemPoster.text = posterName
        }
        //Code the causes the problem
        val manager = (rowMain!!.context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
        val posterAvatarFragment =
                AvatarFragment.newInstance(poster)
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.reply_avatar_fragment, posterAvatarFragment, "ReplyAvatarFragment")
                .commit()
       //End Code the causes the problem
    }
    bindReplies(rowMain, ph, reply.replies)
    return rowMain

}
internal class ListRowHolder(row: View?) {
    var itemDetail : TextView = row!!.reply_view_detail
    var itemImage : ImageView = row!!.reply_view_image
    var itemPoster : TextView = row!!.reply_view_posterName
    var itemLastActive : TextView= row!!.reply_view_lastActive
    var itemReplyReplies: ListView = row!!.reply_view_replyList
}
private fun bindReplies(viewRow: View?, ph: Phan, replies : ArrayList<Reply>){
    if(replies.isNotEmpty()) {
        val myObject = AdapterReply(context, ph, replies)
        val replyListView = viewRow!!.reply_view_replyList
        Log.d("AdapterReply", "Binding Replies: ${ph.encodedId} ${replies.size}")
        replyListView.adapter = myObject
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for you to use a fragment inside your listview? I think it adds unnecessary complexity and it'd be more efficient to inflate an equivalent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
manager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.reply_avatar_fragment, posterAvatarFragment, "ReplyAvatarFragment")
            .commit()
```

Man, I'm not sure do you know, what function performs adapter class in listview. Adapter class is used to fill listview by rows passed in array inside class constructor. **getView** method is called for every row in array, so for example, if you have an array with 10 rows, this code will fire ten times. If you do automatically change fragment to another, and during filling an old view you will change layout to a another layout with the same data, your code will make an infinity loop, because you will repeat all time the same cases. You should avoid actions, which will dynamically change layout during load him. In my sugestion, if you want to use a multiple layouts inside one adapter, there are two special methods to set layout for row, based on some conditions: [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) and [getViewTypeCount](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()). In first one you can use your conditions to check, which layout should be used for row. Second one is to set number of layouts, which will be used in your adapter class. Let search some examples of usage.

Comment: Thanks, I do need to put the fragment in there. This app is like a forum with posts and replies and the fragment contains the logic to display the authors image/badge(it is used all over in the app).  I am going to look into other solutions then the listView.  Maybe make it a recyleView?